# How to start the activity from a particular location and of particular size , not covering the full screen

Tags: android

I want to startactivity at a particular location and also of particular size without covering the fullscreen . Plz anybody suggest on it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "startactivity at a particular location and also of particular size without covering the fullscreen" - by the way which particular location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following in that particular activity to show at specific `gravity`(left/right/top/bottom) and `Layout`(hight/width) of the activity in OnCreate() method.

```
        getWindow().setGravity(gravity);
        getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        getWindow().setAttributes(a);
```

More you can here in **[DeveloperSite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)**

**EDIT** This is how I used ,

```
         android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = getWindow().getAttributes(); 

         WMLP.height =100;   
         WMLP.width = 100;               
         getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP); 
         getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Thanks Frankenstein, I have tried only setlayout is working, setgravity is not working. can you post some examples

Comment: Thanks above code is working but its setting the height and width of activity . Is there any way to set the height , width and gravity of whole window and also to remove the black background  of whole window.

Comment: first black is because..android default bgcolor is black..try adding bgcolor as transparent..the way you asking to set the height , width and gravity of whole window..I dont understand what you mean by "window"

Answer (score 2):

activity will always cover whole screen . although you can choose any portion of screen as active content  . for this make activity transparent (use transparent theme or give background #000000) . now the portion  have a non-transparent background is your appl.

in case you are thinking about things on home screen .they are Widget . so make app widget .

if you did not got answer please tell what exactly you are looking for .

Comment: Thanks shailendra , I got you approach . But I want to start my activity from a particular location only.

Comment: so what you think ??? you can show two activities simultaneously ??? if you read whole post and believe i am wrong somewhere , please explain your opinion .

Comment: @Amit : lets take example that you want to show Activity at lower half only , so give padding upto upperhalf to the layout so rest of the screen will be invisible .

Comment: @ShailendraRajawat nothing personal,,,I dont say i am master if you wish i can take back my minus vote..but i have given the answer..check that..and if that doesn't work ..tell me..